# BLPAPI synchronous session to get SUMMARY event data only

Tags: python, subscription, blpapi

Based on an example/demo Python code application will do async subscription for events when `eventHandler` is supplied.

Example code for that looks like:

```
    print("Session options: %s" % session_options)
    eventHandler = SubscriptionEventHandler()
    # Create a Session
    session = blpapi.Session(session_options, eventHandler.processEvent)
```

that will create subscription session which will return all events.

So in case of a synchronous session I expect to create a session which will looks like

```
     session = blpapi.Session(session_options)
```

but then how can I specify events which I want to subscribe (`SUMMARY` in my case) and only for a one time? [Python BLPAPI SDK](https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/python/3.13/_autosummary/blpapi.AbstractSession.html#blpapi.AbstractSession) says something about `nextEvent()` but I can't find any example how to use it.

Comment: A similar question to G R, what exactly are you looking for? Something you can find in the Bloomberg Terminal under FLDS? Like CUSIP, or maturity? I don't use subscriptions yet, because I believe they are mostly used for real-time price feeds, etc..

Answer (score 0):

If just want to get a one time snapshot, then you don't want to create a subscription. Just use the reference data service instead(/blp/refdata) and request the fields you want for the list of securities you are interested in. Subscriptions are continuous updates.

https://data.bloomberglp.com/labs/sites/2/2013/12/blpapi-developers-guide-1.38.pdf